# Windows Task Scheduler not copying file in Python script

Tags: python, windows, copy, taskscheduler

I have created a python 2.7 script that runs as a scheduled task in Windows. One of the tasks in the script is to copy a file after another operation has completed. If i run the script manually from the command prompt all operations finish successfully. However the same script ran from the task scheduler completes all the operations except for the copy operation. It throws no errors.

I have tried using:

os.system()

shutil.copy()

shutil.copy2()

subprocess.call()

All of these produce the same results. The manual process works but the task scheduler will not copy the file. I have also tried setting the Start In setting in the scheduled task to the current working directory and it still does not work. So i removed it and provided full working paths to all the files

```
import os

Kams = """Z:\\Dir1\\"""

JXDir = """C:\\Dir2\\"""

zip = '2019-01-07_D.zip'

os.system('copy ' + JXDir + zip + ' ' + Kams)
```

If i print the copy line the command looks fine.

Comment: If your `os.system()` call fails to copy, it will write an error message about this to `stderr`. But you will not see that using `os.system()`. Use `subprocess.communicate()` instead of `os.system()`, capture the `stdout` and `stderr` streams, and save them to logfiles, let Task Scheduler run your Python program and see what the logs say. If there are no logs then Task Scheduler isn't running your program at all. That might be because it can't find `python.exe` or it might be because `python.exe` can't find your Python program.

Comment: I figured this out. The Z drive is a mapped drive. If i use the full UNC path it copies it fine.